# Необходимо вычислить разность между суммой ряда и константой с заданной точностью delta

Tags: c, математика, ряды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне не понятно, почему сложение не происходит циклично, а заканчивается на втором члене ряда. Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>  
double f(int n)//вычисление n-ого члена
{
    return pow(-1,n+1)/pow(n,4);
}

int main()
{
    double pi;pi=3.141592;
    double delta;
    printf("delta =");
    scanf("%lf", &delta);
    double a_1, a_n;//переменные предыдущего и текущего членов ряда
    double sum = 0;//сумма ряда
    int n = 0;
    n++;
    a_n = f(n);
    sum += a_n;
    printf("sum-c(input) = %lf\n",fabs(sum-(7*pow(pi,4)/720)));
    while (fabs(sum -(7*pow(pi,4)/720) > delta))
    {    
        a_1 = a_n;
        n++;
        a_n = f(n);
        sum +=a_n;     
    printf("sum=%lf\n",sum);
    printf("sum-c(in cycle) = %lf\n",fabs(sum-(7*pow(pi,4)/720)));
    }
        getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну-ка, посмотрим

```
while (fabs(sum -(7*pow(pi,4)/720) > delta))
```

Условие -

```
fabs(sum -(7*pow(pi,4)/720) > delta)
```

Так от чего же вы берете `fabs`? От

```
sum -(7*pow(pi,4)/720) > delta
```

Дальше рассказывать или не нужно?

А вообще-то я бы делал так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    const double pi = 3.1415926;
    const double theor_sum = 7.0*pi*pi*pi*pi/720.0;
    double delta;
    printf("delta = ");
    scanf("%lf", &delta);
    double sum = 0;
    for(int n = 1; fabs(sum-theor_sum) > delta; ++n)
    {
        sum += (2*(n%2)-1)/((double)n*n*n*n);
        printf("sum = %lf\n",sum);
        printf("sum-c(in cycle) = %lf\n",fabs(sum-theor_sum));
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: а почему решили не использовать pow для возведения в степень?) Раз math,h заинклудили.

Comment: Терпеть ненавижу для таких простых вещей, как возведения в небольшие целочисленные степени, использовать вызовы функций. Так быстрее + компилятор заинлайнит...

Comment: Мне понятен ваш код во всем,за исключением одного момента.Перед возведением n в 4ю степень вы написали (double),не могли бы разъяснить ,почему так нужно делать.P.S.За исправление спасибо , даже стыдно стало,что проблема вся просто в невнимательности.

Comment: Просто без этого все операнды - целочисленные, и в результате целочисленное деление приведет к тому, что все члены, кроме первого, будут равны 0.